# Mysql how to order by highest count column to lowest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table as linkage with below values

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ company_id +  industry +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1      +    a      +
+     2      +    b      +
+     3      +    a      +
+     4      +    c      +
+     5      +    a      +
+     6      +    c      +
+     7      +    a      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

a has count 4, c has count 2, b has count 1

i wish to return query for

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ company_id +  industry +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1      +    a      +
+     3      +    a      +
+     5      +    a      +
+     7      +    a      +
+     4      +    c      +
+     6      +    c      +
+     2      +    b      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query below uses a subquery which separately counts the number of records for every `industry`. The result of it is then join back again on the original table and orders the records by the total count from the subquery.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT industry, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY industry
        ) b ON a.industry = b.industry
ORDER BY b.totalCount DESC, a.company_ID ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1038/1)

For faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `industry`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well. It is counting the occurance of each industry as a group. Then group by that number. (SQLFIDDLE is very handly tool)

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b56/3):

```
select a.company_id, a.industry,
      (select count(*) as cnt from tbl b
       where a.industry = b.industry) as order_by
 from tbl a
 order by order_by desc;
```